# Making a schedule with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a schedule determining who is going to cook and who is doing dishes for a trip with some friends.
I have the names for the participants listed in column "A" and using CountIf to see how many times the specific person appears on the schedule to make it fair for everyone. The code picks 2 random persons for cooking and 2 for dishes making sure they are not the same. Then putting those names into the schedule I have defined in the worksheet.
My current code looks like this and is working so far as intended.

```
Private Sub cookplan()
last_row = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Dim awesome()
Dim index1 As Integer
Dim index2 As Integer
Dim cook1 As String
Dim cook2 As String
Dim dish1 As String
Dim dish2 As String
ReDim awesome(last_row - 1, 0)
For i = 0 To last_row - 1
    awesome(i, 0) = Range("A" & i + 1)
Next

For i = 1 To 5
        index1 = Int((last_row - 1 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
        cook1 = awesome(index1, 0)
        Cells(i * 2, 6).Value = cook1

        Do
            index2 = Int((last_row - 1 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
            cook2 = awesome(index2, 0)
            Cells(i * 2, 7).Value = cook2
        Loop While cook2 = cook1

        Do
            index1 = Int((last_row - 1 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
            dish1 = awesome(index1, 0)
        Loop While dish1 = cook1 Or dish1 = cook2

        Do
            index2 = Int((last_row - 1 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
            dish2 = awesome(index2, 0)
        Loop While dish2 = cook1 Or dish2 = cook2 Or dish2 = dish1

        Cells(i * 2, 8).Value = dish1
        Cells(i * 2, 9).Value = dish2
Next
End Sub
```

Is there a way to make a name appear a maximum and minimum number of times? As it is now, 2 or 3 times seems to be a fair number when I run the code and look at the CountIf results.

**UPDATE**

I have now gotten the code to work as intended. Each person needs at least one cooking and dishes duty, so the coding looks like this now. I know it is not that pretty, but it gets the job done :)

```
Private Sub cookplan()
last_row = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Dim awesome()
Dim index As Integer
Dim cook1 As String
Dim cook2 As String
Dim dish1 As String
Dim dish2 As String
Dim counter1 As Integer
Dim counter2 As Integer
ReDim awesome(last_row - 2, 0)
For i = 0 To last_row - 2
    awesome(i, 0) = Range("A" & i + 2)
Next
Do
    For i = 1 To 5
        Do
            index = Int((last_row - 2 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
            cook1 = awesome(index, 0)
            Cells(i * 2, 6).Value = cook1
        Loop While Cells(index + 2, 2) > 2 Or Cells(index + 2, 3) > 2
        Do
            index = Int((last_row - 2 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
            cook2 = awesome(index, 0)
            Cells(i * 2, 7).Value = cook2
        Loop While Cells(index + 2, 2) > 2 Or Cells(index + 2, 3) > 2 Or cook2 = cook1
        Do
            index = Int((last_row - 2 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
            dish1 = awesome(index, 0)
            Cells(i * 2, 8).Value = dish1
        Loop While Cells(index + 2, 2) > 2 Or Cells(index + 2, 3) > 2 Or dish1 = cook1 Or dish1 = cook2
        Do
            index = Int((last_row - 2 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
            dish2 = awesome(index, 0)
            Cells(i * 2, 9).Value = dish2
        Loop While Cells(index + 2, 2) > 2 Or Cells(index + 2, 3) > 2 Or dish2 = cook1 Or dish2 = cook2 Or dish2 = dish1
    Next
    counter1 = 0
    counter2 = 0
    For i = 2 To last_row
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = 0 Then
            counter1 = counter1 + 1
        End If
        If Cells(i, 3).Value = 0 Then
            counter2 = counter2 + 1
        End If
    Next
Loop While counter1 > 0 Or counter2 > 0
End Sub
```

Comment: When you randomize things, there is no way to exclude the appearance of  value that already appeared. The only reasonable solution is to check of the person appeared already the max number of times and, if yes, re-run the random to get new names.

Comment: Acutally, you could use the solver instead of vba. Its a built-in addon designed to solve scenarios. There are enough tutorials on the web.

Comment: You could also delete / shrink the list of available names, once a name is used the maximum times. A dictionary would be nice for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put your random generation in a separte function, that checks the worksheet, if the selected name has already been used twice. If false, it returns the name. If true, the function calls itself (hence generates a new name), until a name is found, which fits your criteria.

**Update** Please note, that this is some kind of pseudo-code, which is not intended to work

In your Sub cookplan, you add the name of the Function everytime you need a new name

```
cook1 = GetName()
```

After the End Sub you insert a new Funktion called GetName (or whatever you want)

```
Function GetName() As String

    'Determine your name here
    If CountForDeterminedName > 2 Then

        'Call Function Again to find another Name
        GetName = GetName()

    Else

        GetName = DeterminedName

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Your initial comment made me think and come to a solution. Not as smooth but it is something. See the update in my post :) And thank you